# Best practices for Ecto Associations

Tags: elixir, ecto

When handling models with associations, what is the best practice to load associated models: to use *Repo.preload* explicitly or specifying associations that should be pre-loaded when defining a Query?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are equivalent so any approach is fine, really. Make it part of the query if you want to have everything in one place. `Repo.preload/2` is useful when, for some reason, the query has already been performed.